# How to have pip install the latest revision of gensim via. git

Tags: git, pip

I'm trying to install gensim with the [below bug fix](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/doc2vec_inner.pyx):

```
# scipy <= 0.15
try:
     from scipy.linalg.blas import fblas
except ImportError:
     # in scipy > 0.15, fblas function has been removed
     import scipy.linalg.blas as fblas
```

But both of the following, to my surprise, refuses to install the latest head revision and sticks to 0.12.1 which does not have the fix.

```
pip install --user git+git://github.com/piskvorky/gensim.git@master
pip install --user git+git://github.com/piskvorky/gensim.git@6296f86e98
```

How do I install the latest revision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your answer is more a workaround, I'll try to explain what went wrong.

Most projects use the `master` branch as their development branch. `gensim` however uses a separate branch called `develop`.

Instead of cloning the master, you may want to clone the development branch

```
pip install git+https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim.git@develop
```

It is true that the git prefix clones the repository and is therefore rather slow. But if done correctly it gives you a very fine control over what state of the repository you would like to install.

Comment: This still doesn't explain git+git://github.com/piskvorky/gensim.git@6296f86e98 which is on the develop branch, but I'll accept it for spotting the incorrect branch mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @simonzack, `pip install -e git+git://github.com/piskvorky/gensim.git@6296f86e98#egg=gensim` seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the zip works and is faster than cloning:

```
pip install --user https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/archive/develop.zip
```